# Resource files in Swift 4 test project

Tags: unit-testing, swift4

I'm working on a Swift 4 project.

I don't use Xcode.

My project has the following structure:

`Swift4Proj/
    Package.swift
    Sources/
    Tests/
        SwiftProjTests/
            Resources/
                binary.data
            Test1.swift
            Test2.swift
            BinaryFileTest.swift`

A test case needs to get data from a service and compare it with data in the **binary.data** file. To do that it has to read the data from the **binary.data** file:

```
class BinaryFileTests: XCTestCase {

    func testBinaryResponse() {
         // read data from the binary.data file

    }
}
```

I have a couple of questions here:

- how to mark the **binary.data** file as a resource?
- how to get path to the file in the test code?